# read data from a given IP address in a VC++(VS2010) program?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Hi all I am programming a biomedical patient monitoring device. I need to read data from it using IP address 192.168.185.146. Can someone please tell me how to read any data from any IP address using VC++. I am using Visual Studio 2010. and I am using one simple win32 application. I know the packet structure and packet definition of the device data..
I am new to VC++ programming and I don't know how to read data from and write data to a IP port given only its address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest You reading about sockets programming in general (http://beej.us/guide/) and winsock/windows sockets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740673%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

There You will/can/may find everything You are saerching for...
If You don´t know anything about it at the moment it would be kind of useless to You if we would just tell You names of functions etc...

Comment: Thank you for the information... I really needed that. I am going through the materials right now...